# (Author, Date) type of bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I've been trying in vain to find how to have a (Author, Date) type of bibliography.

Could you help me with that?

Thanks!

Comment: How about using `biblatex` with the `authoryear` style ?

Comment: You may have a look at package `natbib`.

Answer (score 3):

In order to have an (Author, Date) bibliographystyle in the text, I used the `\usepackage[round]{natbib}` package, and I used the `apalike` bibliography style : `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`. In your text, you have to use the `\citep{}` command.